# Read and write XML files in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I need to write an HTML page that has multiple input fields in which the site administrator would write config values for a website.

Then these values should be written into an XML file that exists on the server.

I already have javascript code that reads from an XML file and it works fine, however I can't find any example code on how to write values back into the file, any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: I would not suggest trying to do server side javascript to write it. Try using PHP or ASP or whatever platform your webserver supports.

Comment: Basically, just write the file out as you need it.

Comment: @CraigTrombly: What? Node.js?  Also, ASP is dead, and PHP should be.

Comment: Choose whatever language yur webserver supports, it is just server side code, don't worry about suggestions i give (they were merely meant to give you an idea and I did not want to list the hundreds of ways you can do this) ALSO, make sure the file has read/write/modify permissions for the context that you run this in.

Comment: so guys, it can't be done in something client side like javascript? I'm really new to web development and wouldn't know where to begin if I wanted to do it in, say, PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a server-side script that accepts your modified content and writes it back to the XML file.
You can execute it using an AJAX POST.

Make sure not to open any security holes.